# Where can I ask theoretical questions?

Tags: discussion, scope

I was wondering where the proper place for theoretical questions would be. 
E.g. (a little noobish, but whatever) I wondered how it's possible for something to be closed source - why can't you either look at the file or look at what the programme is making the computer do, and reverse engineer the code?

Comment: [programmers.se] could be a possibility. As to reverse engineering, it is a very difficult endeavour. Look at how far [Wine](http://winehq.org) and [ReactOS](https://www.reactos.org/) have got by reverse engineering.

Comment: Thanks! that's very interesting. Also, in the future I'll look there for answers!